# Drupal node generates unwanted html while rendering

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, ckeditor

I added content on drupal backend in backend content looks good like below (in table also)

```
<p><a href="http://myur.coml"><span style="font-size:18px;"><strong>CLICK TO WATCH</strong></span></a></p>
```

But in view or preview the above element rendered as like below(inspected in chrom),

```
<p><a href="<a href=" http:="">http://myurl.com</a>"&gt;<span style="font-size:18px;"><strong>CLICK TO WATCH</strong></span></p>
```

I tried clearing cache, checked database table for the value but whatever i tried `<a href=" http:="">http://myurl.com</a>"&gt` this part is messed up, any idea?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of ckeditor settings?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by disabling the "Convert URLs into links" setting of the input format.

Go to Administer > Site Configuration > Input Formats, click "configure" next to the particular (whichever you are using it) input format, and disable the "Convert URLs into links". This setting is responsible for turning email addresses and URLs into links.